# How to find a polynomial of least degree with some of its points given?

Tags: functions

$f(x)$ is a polynomial function of least degree which satisfies the following relations:

$f(0)=0$

$f(1)=9$

$f(2)=8$

$f(3)=7$

$f(4)=6$

$f(5)=5$

What is the value of $f(6)$ $?$

Comment: What does "least powered" mean?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Math.SE! It is mandatory to show some of your thoughts/some effort to solve the question. Where do you get stuck? What is meant by least powered?

Comment: $f(x)=10-x $  So  $f(6)=4$

Comment: f(0)=0 but 10-0=10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g(x) =f(x)-(10-x)\;,$ Where $x=1,2,3,4,5$ are the roots of $g(x) =0$.

Then Using factor theorem, Here $(x-1),(x-2),(x-3),(x-4),(x-5)$

are the roots of $g(x) =0$

So we can write $$g(x) = f(x)-(10-x) = A(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)(x-5)$$

So $$f(x) = A(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)(x-5)+10-x\;,$$ Now put $x=0$

$f(0) = -120A+10 = 0$

So we get $\displaystyle A = \frac{1}{12}$

So we get $$\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{1}{12}(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)(x-5)+10-x$$

so we get $$\displaystyle f(6) = \frac{1}{12}\times 120+(10-6) = 14$$

Comment: @Piyush First you can assume $A$ to be a polynomial. Later it becomes clear that $A$ can be chosen constant which makes $f$ of minimal degree.